# How to build and deploy multiple lambdas from single repo using codepipeline?

Tags: aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, sam

**UseCase:**

I have a `codecommit` repo that has 12 lambdas(6 `nodejs` and 6 `python`) and a cloud formation template. My goal is to build all the lambdas using codebuild and upload them as zip files to s3. After that,  I have to pass the uploaded lambdas bucket keys to cloudformation template.

**What I know ?**

I know using SAM template you can use `sam package or cloudformation package` command to build and upload them to s3. But I don't have SAM template instead I have cloudformation one.

**What i tried ?**

I wrote a bash script in buildspec.yml which will go into every lambda folder and build and copy the lambda to s3 bucket with the name `lambdafolder.zip` where lambdafolder means lambda 1,2..12 . I am acheiving what I want but I am hard coding the `S3Key` parameter for all the lambda functions in the cloudformation.

**What i want ?**

I want to know is there any elegant approach to this type of scenario just like `SAM package` command.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks